# Ruby on Rails query to make a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I forked a Ruby on Rails project from  https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website but I'm new in Ruby.

I need to make a list with a column of usernames and another column with the sum of changes made by that user.

As you can see, there is a table named "changesets" in the database:

> irb(main):002:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
>
> => ["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata", "current_way_tags", "current_ways", "diary_entries", "friends", "gps_points",
>   "gpx_file_tags", "messages", "gpx_files", "users", "way_tags", "ways",
>   "user_preferences", "user_tokens", "way_nodes", "diary_comments",
>   "current_relations", "current_node_tags", "node_tags",
>   "current_relation_tags", "nodes", "acls", "relation_tags",
>   "current_way_nodes", "current_nodes", "current_relation_members",
>   "changesets", "relation_members", "changeset_tags", "languages",
>   "relations", "oauth_nonces", "oauth_tokens", "user_roles", "notes",
>   "user_blocks", "client_applications", "note_comments", "redactions",
>   "changesets_subscribers", "changeset_comments", "reports", "issues",
>   "issue_comments", "diary_entry_subscriptions", "delayed_jobs"]

And the changesets table have the following columns:

> irb(main):007:0> Changeset.column_names
>
> => ["id", "user_id", "created_at", "min_lat", "max_lat", "min_lon", "max_lon", "closed_at", "num_changes"]

And the users table have the following columns:

> irb(main):008:0> User.column_names
>
> => ["email", "id", "pass_crypt", "creation_time", "display_name", "data_public", "description", "home_lat", "home_lon", "home_zoom",
>   "nearby", "pass_salt", "image_file_name", "email_valid", "new_email",
>   "creation_ip", "languages", "status", "terms_agreed", "consider_pd",
>   "auth_uid", "preferred_editor", "terms_seen", "description_format",
>   "image_fingerprint", "changesets_count", "traces_count",
>   "diary_entries_count", "image_use_gravatar", "image_content_type",
>   "auth_provider", "home_tile", "tou_agreed", "ranked"]

An user can have several changesets, but each changeset belongs to only one user. So the second column of my list should be the sum of the num_changes of all the changesets of that user.

How could I display that information?
I think it would be something like this:

```
<% User.each do |user| %>
  <li><b><%= user.display_name %></b> - <%= NEED HELP IN THIS PART %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `user.changesets.size`?

Comment: If u have the required number of  `changesets` related to the user then count like `user.changesets.count`. My question is what is the use of num_changes in the changesets column?

Comment: Rajkumar P, inside a changeset may exist one or more changes. A changeset is a group of changes done in a short period of time and saved together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First join the changesets table and select a sum of num_changes.

```
@users = User.joins(:changesets)
  .select('users.*, SUM(changesets.num_changes) AS sum_num_changes')
  .group(:id)
```

This will give you a `sum_num_changes` attribute on all the user instances just like if it was a column on the users table.

Use `.left_joins(:changesets)` instead of `.joins(:changesets)` to create a LEFT OUTER JOIN if you want rows from users without any matches in the `changesets` table.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li><b><%= user.display_name %></b> - <%= user.sum_num_changes %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm doing those commands at Rails console, the first one did show all the users and the tables, but the second one gave me sysntax error  
Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError ((irb):16: syntax error, unexpected '.')
  .select('users.*, SUM(changese...
  ^

Comment: Or should I do it inside a file?

Comment: You can create a class method (aka a scope) in your user model or do in in your controller. I'm guessing that syntax error is from copypasting into the console. It looks like a rogue quote somewhere is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.changesets.sum(:num_changes)
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum

Comment: That relation is already defined in the user model. It is showing the same results as changesets.count, not the sum of num_changes, which is what I need

Comment: user.changeset.sum(:num_changes), edited my answer. Above will work.

Comment: This one gives me Application Error page "The OpenStreetMap server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request (HTTP 500)"